# How to manage user authentication over multiple applications in .net core

Tags: authorization, .net-core

I have less knowledge of .Net Core. I have an application which is hosted on suppose `"localhost://5000"`. It's my main application from where user navigate to various applications like App1 and App2.

1. App1 is hosted on `localhost://5001`
2. App2 is hosted on `localhost://5002`

Before navigating to app1 and app2 . I want the user should be logged in the application.

Currently, I have perform logging in the main application. and all the `Action method` which is annotated with `"Authorize"` attribute is accessible by the user. But not able to access the authorize method which is reside in `App1` and `App2` .

As per my knowledge, user is not signed in the context of `App1` and `App2` that's why i am getting `401`.

How can i solve this problem? I want to implement this in professional way.

Please suggest...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly.You can tackle it with single sign-on and authentication.
One way to implement it is using OAuth2 and/or OpenIdConnect.
In such case, you need to have a separate application which acts authorization server and App1 App2 etc will use that authorization server as clients.

With the single sign on the user will sign into the authorization server only once.Let's say the user is trying to access the main application(Still not signed in).Then the user is redirected to the authorization server.The user enters his/her username and password.Press a sign button to sign in to the authorization server.

After successful sign in at authorization server, the user is redirected back to the main application.

And then when the user tries to navigate into App1 (for the first time after sign in) it will redirect the user to the authorization server.But since the user is already logged in user is redirected back to App1.

Described above is related to implicit flow which is commonly used in applications run in browsers.
Please have a look at this to get an idea about OAuth2 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

[IdentiyServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html) is a OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect implementation for .NetCore.

I did use words main application and App1 and App2 since it is mentioned in the question, in the context of authentication related to OAuth2 all three are clients of the authorization server.